# AWS import Snapshot stuck at 43%

Tags: amazon-web-services, import

I see a weird problem where the import-image task is stuck at 43% it has been like this for the past 2 days any ideas would be helpful. Steps used are pretty normal:

Used [these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-import-snapshot.html) to import a snapshot to AWS through EC2.

[image: Screenshot of the AWS code]